# update product price by using product sku in csv file

Tags: product

Magento update price of product through CVS by using product sku. To improve system performance.

Comment: please provide more information and your code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); 
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$store  = 1

$skuIndex = 0;
$priceIndex = 1;

$prodCount=0;
$csv = "file_name.csv";


$io = new Varien_Io_File();
$productIdsByPrice = array();
$productModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
$io->streamOpen($csv, 'r');
while($csvData = $io->streamReadCsv()){
    if (count($csvData) < 2) { 
        continue;
    }
    $sku = trim($csvData[$skuIndex]);
    $id = $productModel->getIdBySku($sku);
    if ($id) {
        $price = trim($csvData[$priceIndex]);
        if (!isset($productIdsByPrice[$price])) {
            $productIdsByPrice[$price] = array();
        }
        $productIdsByPrice[$price][] = $id;
    }
}

$resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeAdapter   = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
try{
    $writeAdapter->beginTransaction();
    foreach ($productIdsByPrice as $price => $ids) {
    Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
                $ids,array('price' => $price), $store );
        }
$writeAdapter->commit();
}catch (Exception $e) {
    $writeAdapter->rollback();
}
?>
```